# Sigma's for Sony can be calibrated with Sigma Docker. What about Sony lenses?

Tags: sony, sigma

So, I am so confused on this topic, as I can't find an information anywhere. Sigma 3 years ago introduced amazing tool - Sigma Docker that allows without having special equipment or extraordinary skills, to re-calibrate to 'fail-focusing' Sigma lenses (this is especially important for 85mm F1.4 ART, where even if focus goes to 'nose' instead of 'eye' we can already see that).
But Sigma lenses are much more heavier than Sony's lenses. An Sony has 100mm E-mount lens that is probably twice lighter than Sigma's 105mm F1.4 lens that even have the 'mouting socket' for tripod (which says that it is way to heavy for regular holding in hands if photographer is not a 'body-builder').
So how i.e. does Sony 100mm lens for E-mount is callibrated? Is is still old-way that we have to send it to 'service' and they do have laboratory, draw lines on sheets of paper etc., and do the adjustments with screwdriver?

Comment: **TLDR; please clarify your question**...There seems to be a lot of extra, unnecessary information in your question - causing your question to become muddled. Are you asking how to calibrate a Sigma lens destined for a Sony E-mount camera? Are you asking if the E-mount can handle a heavy lens? Are you asking if special calibration is necessary when using heavy lenses? Are you asking how to calibrate a Sony E-mount lens? You've used tags destined for editing (color-management/display-calibration) - why? Are you asking how calibration affects color?

Comment: @MichaelC not obvious to me at all

Comment: The two calibration tools they use might be the stock shelf and the junk bin :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Sigma dock only works with select Sigma lenses. The lens needs to have the needed firmware to respond to the commands sent by the dock. Even Sigma lenses that are not part of their 'Global Vision' selection (ART, Sports, Contemporary) can not be calibrated using the Sigma USB dock.

> So how i.e. does Sony 100mm lens for E-mount is calibrated? Is is still old-way that we have to send it to 'service' and they do have laboratory, draw lines on sheets of paper etc., and do the adjustments with screwdriver?

**Since all Sony E-mount cameras are mirrorless, there's not much need for the type of calibration done by Sigma's dock for lenses used with reflex cameras that have a separate PDAF sensor.** Because mirrorless cameras use the main imaging sensor to do contrast detection autofocusing, there should be no focusing errors attributable to different optical distances between the AF sensor and the imaging sensor. After all, it's the same sensor used for both.

If a Sony E-mount lens is not focusing properly with an E-mount camera, the issue is beyond the scope of what the Sigma dock allows the end user to do with certain Sigma lenses. So yes, one would need to send the lens to an authorized Sony service center and have it checked out. How they do that is probably a bit more sophisticated than "draw lines on sheets of paper etc., and do the adjustments with screwdriver?"